# Should an answer like this really be deleted?

Tags: discussion, deleted-answers, specific-answer

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/30635010) was deleted in a review as a thank you and not-an-answer. But I believe it did state the nature of the problem in the second of the three sentences

> The old code is a little sparse on "IMPLICIT NONE" and so the solution
> was that IVRLOC needed to be declared with an 8 byte output.

Where does the line lie? Is this sentence not enough?

BTW, the only dissenting vote was from an expert for this language tag.

Comment: They're just thanking everyone and then repeating what was already in an answer, so yes, question closure was *very* appropriate.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels Repeating what? It was the very first answer to that question. And it confirms that the solution offered in a comment actually helped.

Comment: This is a common problem I encounter in the Low quality queue. Askers tend to post thank-you answers when there are no actual other answers and reviewers tend to miss that. If only they knew the proper way to turn a comment into an answer which is: ***post a community wiki linking to the comment and attributing the commenter***. This way it would be easier for reviewers to see that it's an actual answer from a comment and not a thank-you

Comment: @Tomerikoo or we as community can do that if we are so inclined. We don't have to wait the asker or the commenter to do the right thing™.

Comment: Because _**posting a community wiki linking to the comment and attributing the commenter**_ doesn't take any extra effort at all and is so intuitive that my 4-year-old could do it with her eyes closed. ... Honestly, I don't even know what that means.

Answer (score 63):

Typically, "thank you" answers should be deleted, yes.

In this case, however, it's not just a "thank you" answer. Someone answered in the comments, and the OP posted that solution as an answer, albeit in a less-than-crystal clear way. This is... actually exactly what *should* happen, *if* the original user who solved the problem in comments can't be bothered to post the solution as an answer (this situation is exactly the kind of reason why **users should not answer in the comments**). This specific comment is forgivable, since it is really a question (whose answer ended up leading the asker to the solution) asking for more details/clarity.

The reviewers in this case performed the wrong action because they did not have or understand the full context of the situation... or allowed themselves to get distracted by the "thank you `<user>`" at the beginning of the answer.

However, the original commenter has since come along and posted the solution themselves as a proper answer. So everything is ship-shape, as it were.

Comment: I just hope it doesn't end up in an audit because it would be a patently unfair one. Without opening the question to check for answers the conclusion should be the reverse, that is the answer should stay. But it shouldn't because Mr. comment as answer went back and made an answer of it.

Comment: @Joshua That's one reason why you should always open the question to view more context when reviewing in those queues.

Comment: In this case, posting the comment as an answer instead would be guessing. A good guess, but a guess nonetheless. The question is wholly insufficient for anything other than guessing.

Comment: @francescalus Your comment needs some clarification for me to understand fully. Are you referring to the comment being posted as an answer by the original commenter? If so, yes, I agree with you, as I said in my answer already. If you are referring to the comment being posted as an answer by the question asker, then no, it's not a guess; it's OP confirming the comment helped them solve their problem. Sometimes questions can themselves be answers (google "Socratic method"), for what it's worth.

Comment: Naturally I agree that the question asker confirming the comment is not a guess (hence my review), but this is the only person who could have answered in such a way. Although you say the first (non-OP) comment was "forgivable" (I agree), I read the parts of your answer leading up to that as contrary, suggesting it would be reasonable, or correct, for the commenter to answer instead (Socratic or otherwise). Perhaps you agree with my reading, in which case you may find a clearer way to redraft; or you may disagree with my reading and we can leave it at that

Comment: With francescalus on this one. There is a complete lack of cause and effect that makes the question and answer something that's hard to learn from. The results can only be emulated. If it works for you, groovy. But if it doesn't, there are no breadcrumbs to be followed and no explanation of why it worked in the context of the question. Janneb's answer adds some of the breadcrumbs.

Comment: @user4581301 I'm not sure what that comment is replying to. This isn't about "is this a good example of a question and answer", it's about "was this post correctly deleted in review".

Comment: Apologies. No it should not have been deleted. It's an answer. Not a good one, but that's what downvotes are for.

Comment: When in doubt, **NEVER SAY THANKS**.

Comment: There is nothing wrong with deleting low quality slop even if it somehow vaguely resembles an answer to the question. If someone wished to post an answer based on comments, that is fine, but then they should do so properly by putting an utter minimum of effort into the answer, not in the form of some thank you speech. This answer was correctly deleted regardless of what other answers that may or may not have been present. There is no mandatory obligation for SO users to hug crap.

Comment: @Lundin I don't see how you can actually read the answer being discussed and come to that conclusion. It *literally* says in it "the solution was that IVRLOC needed to be declared with an 8 byte output". That doesn't "vaguely resemble an answer", it **is** an answer. If you CBA to edit posts that need some improvement, that's fine, but please don't mislead folks into doing the wrong thing by deleting stuff because it has the word "thanks" in it.

Comment: @TylerH No that's a brief comment in passing, not an answer. A mediocre or higher quality answer would contain a simple code example showing the necessary fix in a context relevant to the question.

Comment: @Lundin, the answer could indeed show code with the necessary fix: `integer*8 ivrloc`. I hope that's familiar because `integer*8 nxloc` is right there in the question to declare that variable as a 64-bit integer. Not declaring the type of a function result is an utterly basic Fortran error that needs no elaboration at all once that has been pointed out.

Comment: @francescalus In which case the question is of "a simple typo" nature... which only makes the answer even lower quality because such questions shouldn't be answered... In fact that's yet another reason to delete-vote the answer, because if an answer to a close question would somehow end up with up-votes or accept, it would block roomba from deleting the whole thing.

Comment: (-1) from me on this Answer (even if I usually agree with 90(+)% of your Postings (on Meta) @A), because of: "the kind of reason why users should not answer in the comments" => Then oops...!, I do that in 70%-80% of the Threads (in my "small" Tag) I answer... (Mostly 1-Rep Users, fairly LQ, with "too many" Tags (thinking more chance to get an Answer), get their Qt quickly downvoted, then I don't bother putting some "Effort" in a Qlt Answer, I just give the Sol  in a Comment, knowing the Thread/Qt will anyway get deleted by the next 'Romba' Clean-Up as those 1-Rep Users never accept Answers...)

Comment: @chivracq: Yup, agreed, when the question seems like a lost beginner, where an answer would just be clutter for future searches, I often basically answer in comments, especially if it's just some explanation and a link to a near-duplicate.

Comment: @chivracq Anything that's useful as a comment in terms of solving the problem is typically fine as an answer. The main benefit of posting it as an answer vs a comment (aside from that being how the system is designed and all the accompanying workflows) is that you can edit it beyond 5 minutes, and others can edit it too, if you can't bother to "put some 'Effort'" into it. Also, the majority of such questions *don't* get deleted, in case you haven't noticed the strong positive trend in total (undeleted) questions over the years... we delete a good few, sure, but certainly less than 10% in total

Comment: @chivracq "those 1-Rep users never accept answers" that's frankly just a wild non-sequitur. All users start out as 1-rep users, and many of them/us do/did accept answers. I also don't see how it is logical to argue you shouldn't provide a solution as an answer because it will Roomba when a comment won't prevent it from Roombaing either. The bar for blocking Roomba is much lower with an answer than it is with comments.

Answer (score 14):

This specific answer should not have been deleted through LQP review.

The answer undoubtedly has certain triggers for LQP deletion that a more experienced (SO-)answer writer would avoid. The leading

> Thank you janneb you answered the question.

can be seen, as the review comment has it, as 'add[ding] "thank you" as an answer'. However, it's clear in this case that this is more acknowledgment or attribution: an actual "answer" follows.

Equally

> Thank you Vladimir for helping me get the question cleaned up so the solution was clearer.

compounds this 'thank you' feeling.

What remains, as quoted in the question here, is very much *the* answer.

These two parts could be edited and perhaps we get an answer more like

> The comment by janneb helps understand the problem. The old code is a little sparse on "IMPLICIT NONE" and so the solution was that IVRLOC needed to be declared with an 8 byte output.

Thanking Vladimir [F] is commentary beyond the answer and would suit more as a comment on the question if made at all. Thanking janneb still happens, but in a less dangerous way. It's possible to argue that janneb needn't be thanked in an answer.

As a "Looks OK" reviewer, perhaps I could have made that change. Why didn't I? Well, that's a new question.

---

Is the answer a good answer? No. Far from it, but it's still not LQP delete-worthy. As a "domain specialist" I'm entitled to down- and delete-vote this answer, but I have no intention to do that.

If we want to delete this answer, the correct way to delete it is by deleting the parent question. The question is a poor question but the given answer is as useful an answer as is possible for it to get.

Yes, the answer could have more detail:

- why does sparsity of IMPLICIT NONE hinder our debugging?
- how does one declare an 8-byte output?

But fundamentally the question isn't worth that effort. There are several ways one can have problems seen in the question:

- perhaps the C interoperability has gone a bit wrong
- there could be some confusion over linking, or selection of modules/procedures
- the return type of one of the functions hasn't been declared
- ...

We have no way of knowing from the question which case we have here: we have no MRE. The best guess, and one that is correct, is that the return type of the function `IVRLOC` hasn't been declared.

In the question, the left-hand side of the assignment had a type explicitly declared, but the right-hand side was using implicit typing.

Does the question asker know about explicit typing of variables? Absolutely.

Does the question asker know about explicit typing of function results? Who can say?

Either way, we don't need yet more Fortran questions where implicit typing gives the wrong behaviour. As the question stands there is no way to know what the correct way to resolve the problem is and "explicitly type the function result" is one way but is not necessarily the way that resolves it for the next person finding this question looking for their own answer. Appropriately using [`implicit none`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/24337413/3157076) would have immediately pointed to this error.

Comment: It's really simple. The answer is crap and should therefore be deleted. It has no value to anyone even if there's a slight hint of answering the question in there, because none would even trust to use the content of an answer. The purpose of SO is not to answer a question in the worst possible way, but the best possible way. In this case someone could turn the comment into a very brief but clean answer and no attribution is even necessary for people who are lazy and answer in comments.

Comment: "If we want to delete this answer, the correct way to delete it is by deleting the parent question." What? No! Where did you get that idea from? This is a perfectly valid question. It may be unclear or too broad but that's no reason to cast delete votes, but to close it.

Comment: That answer is not "crap". The correct behaviour of the program of the question relies on the function result being a 64-bit integer, but the compiler hasn't been told that the function result is 64-bit (so it assumes 32-bit). There is absolutely nothing else valuable to say about the problem. The question is a poor question: if it had an MRE so that we could tell in advance what the answer was (without guessing) it would be closed as a duplicate. But that is no reason to delete a correct answer through LQP. If you feel it's a crap answer, downvote/delete it _as normal_, not as NAA.

Comment: I did not say that the question should be deleted. If an answer says "I called the function `cat` when it should have been `dog`", confirming a typo in the question, that is not an answer that is crap-to-be-deleted. If that answer is useless it is because the question is useless.

Comment: This debate is as old as meta. There's two camps: the crap deleters and the crap huggers. The former deletes crap, the latter goes out of their way to lawyer some reason why crap must not be deleted. And so you can't argue with the crap huggers, because they never look at the overall quality of a post, but only at some pedantic detail. And the crap huggers think it's super-important what flag that was used for the crap to end up in review queues, or what delete reason that was picked, but again they don't care about the actual overall quality of the crap post. ->

Comment: While crap deleters don't care about these reasons as long as crap is removed from the site. For them, flag reasons or delete reasons are the means/tools used for deleting crap and not some holy script that define the very existance of the SO site. I guess there will never be a community consensus until we form some parallel site crapoverflow.com where we can migrate all these "great" posts that must be hugged instead of deleted.

Comment: As I infer you are characterizing me as a crap hugger, could you explain why you think the linked question is "perfectly valid" and why the answer is "crap" and what a non-crap answer to the question would look like? As you haven't downvoted janneb's answer that one's presumably not crap, but I fail to see the subtle distinction/the crap interface between the answers. I tried to explain in my post here why I didn't downvote/deletevote the OP's answer so hopefully I've given you enough to work with in your attempts to convert me to a crap hater.

Comment: The question is a separate issue. The answer is crap because: the first sentence is an irrelevant "thank you". The second sentence is very unclear and broad, nobody including someone who knows the technical specific can tell the meaning of "The old code is a little sparse on "IMPLICIT NONE"". A code example would have been great here. It's also unclear why ""IMPLICIT NONE" would lead to "IVRLOC needed to be declared with an 8 byte output" - this isn't helpful to future readers. Then the third sentence is another thank you fluff one.

Comment: And again, the purpose of SO (according to the crap deleter camp) isn't to preserve everything with a slightest resemblance of answering the question, but to provide high quality Q&A. Anything which isn't of high or at least mediocre quality can be safely deleted - if it contained any relevant information the poster should have invested an utter minimum of effort in presenting that information in a mediocre or better answer.

Comment: As for the answer by janneb it looks like a perfectly valid answer with enough detail to point out the error. I see no reason to down vote it.

Comment: Here's the funny thing: I know exactly what 'The old code is a little sparse on "IMPLICIT NONE"' means. And I also know exactly why using IMPLICIT NONE would lead to  "IVRLOC need[ing] to be declared with an 8 byte output". The audience for the Q&A pair is, unsurprisingly, those people who are using Fortran as a language. If you don't understand what those two sentences mean but immediately call them "unclear and broad" then you are perhaps not someone to whom the answer is meant to appeal. This does not make it crap.

Comment: In this case, pointing out that the return type has not been given is quite sufficient, the additional detail in janneb's answer is entirely extraneous.  Going back to my dog/cat example: saying "I called it `cat` when it should be `dog`" is not helped by adding the further detail "... which means that the compiler is looking for a function called `cat` and it can't find it so it throws an error. The compiler can find a function called `dog` so if I correctly reference that function then the compiler doesn't complain."

Comment: No it doesn't matter what technology it is about - one shouldn't need to read between the lines. Similarly an acceptable answer shouldn't mention "it's a bit sparse on catching exceptions" or "it's a bit sparse on reading the error code" or "you compiled this with too old a version of the compiler" or whatever. Such an answer can never be good in any context. Answers should be explicit, not a bunch of winks and nudges.

Comment: "then you are perhaps not someone to whom the answer is meant to appeal" On the contrary, if the only person who can understand the answer is one who already knows the answer, then it's most definitely a terrible answer of no use to anyone.

Comment: I think we're going to have to call this discussion to a close. I'm reading your final points as an exhortation for me to go to C++, Rust, Haskell, Java, ... tags, or Biblical Hermeneutics, Graphical Design, Interpersonal Skills, ... sites and delete as crap any answer I don't fully understand. That's surely not what you mean, but it does show that we aren't communicating well.

Comment: No you should go and delete every answer where the poster has not made the slightest effort into making anyone understand it.

Comment: Just to to elaborate what @Lundin mentioned: If an answer is not understandable in general, the answer is best left to the personal notebook of the poster, not in SO. The whole purpose here is to help everyone who may face the issue, not in an individual level.

Comment: @SouravGhosh, to quote the answer: " the solution was that IVRLOC needed to be declared with an 8 byte output." I do not see how this would not be understood by anyone reading the answer in the context of having a similar problem to that of the question

Comment: @Lundin  You're equating presentation with quality. They're independent. In a front end example, The website and presentation may be great and eye catching, but the content is what gives quality. If it offers only spam, then the quality is bad. If it offers valuable content albeit in a dumb design, it's still good quality. In calculating quality, you shouldn't be looking at presentation at all, but if you do, it shouldn't account for >10%. Imagine if vaccines quality were based on the wrapper design. If it works, it works even if the wrapper added dumb "Thank you" notes.

Comment: @TheMaster Obviously that isn't true. If the presentation is so bad that the reader don't even realize it is an answer, the quality of the actual answer doesn't matter.

Comment: @Lundin But you're not the reader, but a outside reviewer looking to clean crap. To anyone who is looking for the exact question, the answer is valuable. Gold is gold even if it is covered in crap. To the casual viewer, the entire thing is crap. To the digger with proper tools(like frances), it is gold even if it is fully surrounded by crap. You can't measure quality with just one look. What's inside matters. What's inside the "Thank you"s matters.

Comment: @TheMaster Using that reasoning then why are you here and not on Reddit? The purpose of this site is _high quality_ Q&A, not just barfing out something that may be technically correct but at the same time surrounded by irrelevant distractions. We hold answers to a certain standard here, which is the reason why the site still stands.

Comment: @Lundin I agree with **high quality**. Where we differ is the perception of quality. As I've already said before, your definition of *high quality* means presentation or you give >80% value to the presentation part, whereas crap huggers think quality is what's inside. Presentation can be changed easily. Gold can be washed easily. But what's inside, the gold or the content is hard to come by. That's the quality we're looking for. We don't hug crap, because we like crap, but because we can see beyond the crap and value what's inside, whereas you can see only the crap.

Comment: "This specific answer should not have been deleted through LQP review" it should have been deleted, however method it was done is irrelevant. That post should not stand at it was.

Comment: @TheMaster No it's more like: I'm more willing to trust the quality of the post if written by a person with basic human communication skills. Someone who is at least able to write something at least as formal as a sloppily written business e-mail (or better). Those who aren't capable of expressing themselves with such an utter minimum of formality in written text aren't able to handle any form of theoretical job such as working as a programmer. I wouldn't trust anything they say if they aren't even capable of basic human-to-human communication.